# Mathematica can't solve my integral

Tags: integration, area

Given the function $H:]0,2[\times S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $H(r,\theta)=\frac{\sqrt{r-(1-r^2/2)^2}}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(\theta)+\frac{4}{5}(1-\frac{r^2}{2})^2$ I wanted to compute the volume of the open set $H^{-1}(]\frac{4}{5},\infty[)$ with respect to the form $rdr\wedge d\theta$.

I tried using Mathematica to get values of the expressions of $r,\theta$ such that they are in that pre-image but then when it comes to actually computing the integral I cannot solve it and Mathematica also does not return anything.

Using Mathematica the expression that I obtain for $r$ and $\theta$ are $\cos(x)>\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{5}\sqrt{\frac{16r^3-8r^5+r^7}{8-4r+r^3}}$, which as you can see when you get the $\arcsin$ to solve for $x$ gives a difficult primitive to solve in $r$.

Does anyone know a different way on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is no explicit expression for this result, do you need numerical value?  I believe it is about 1.936

Comment: Ideally I would want the exact value since this relates to trying classify a certain integrable system, but numeric is also nice. How did u get to such value ? @IvanKaznacheyeu.

Comment: Use $c=\cos\theta$, $H > 4/5$, $0<r<2$, $-1\leq c \leq 1$ and make Reduce in reals, which gives $r \in (r_1, 2)$, $c \in (c_1,1]$, where $r_1\approx 0.8658$ is root of some 8-th order algebraic equation, $c_1$ is expression which is similar to your one but is different. Then integrate $2 r \arccos c\;dr$ from $r=r_1$ to $r=2$